# How can I tell that ILMerge has been used

Tags: .net, asp.net, ilmerge

I'd like to be able to tell whether or not an assembly is the output/result from using ILMerge on two different assemblies. It doesn't matter how nitty gritty it is, if I have to parse IL, I'm willing to do it. Is there *anything* that would be indicate that the assembly author used ILMerge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I emailed Mike Barnett, and he told me that ILMerge doesn't leave any signature.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this question might be a one only the ILMerge author can answer.

His name is [Mike Barnett](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/default.aspx), he's a Microsoft employee responsible for ILMerge, Spec#, and CodeContracts. You can try contacting him at mbarnett @ you know where.